# Method not found: System.IO.Stream CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

What could be its reason I am using ASP.Net 1.1

Comment: Some stacktrace from the exception would be helpful

Comment: [MissingMethodException: Method not found: System.IO.Stream CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType).]
   FollowUp.Momfollowup.print(String sFileName) +0
   FollowUp.Momfollowup.PreviewMeeting() in fu_momfollowup.aspx.cs:962

Answer (score 0):

Set crystals assemblies' property "Copy local" to true